# Ways to avoid MySQLdb's "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" (2014) exception

Tags: python, mysql

Following code, using python 2.6.6 and MySQLdb 1.2.2 causes *Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now* MySQLdb exception:

```
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect( db="test", user="root" )
cursor = conn.cursor( MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor )

cursor.execute( "BEGIN; CREATE TABLE t1 ( t1_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ); COMMIT;" )
cursor.execute( "BEGIN; CREATE TABLE t2 ( t2_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ); COMMIT;" )
```

The exception is raised during execution of the second query. As I read, the exception is generally caused by limitations of MySQL's C API implementation, which disallow concurrent query execution.

If I recreate cursor object between above two queries, the problem is worked around but unfortunatelly the solution doesn't seem perfect to me. I have a very simple abstration over database connection and query execution and would prefer not to recreate the cursor after each query execution as it will (as far as I understand it) commit the current transaction and potentially have other side effects.

Therefore, my question is: What are other ways of avoiding this exception? How to prepare the cursor object for execution of next query? Maybe there is some method expected by the Python DB API, which would be relatively neutral when using other database interfaces and will work around the problem in case of MySQLdb?

Thanks in advance for your time and help :)

**Edit:**
After I posted the question, I started to read through the Python DB API spec to read about side effects of cursor destruction (I am not so sure about transaction commit anymore :)) and I found following, alternative work around:

```
cursor.execute( "BEGIN; CREATE TABLE t1 ( t1_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ); COMMIT;" )
while cursor.nextset() is not None: pass
cursor.execute( "BEGIN; CREATE TABLE t2 ( t2_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT );
```

The problem is that I don't know what does it do (it returns `1` two times and `None` after that). Should I dig into this direction? I mean, should I understand concept of these sets to find solution to my problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

DB-API tries to handle transactions on its own, starting a transaction on the first command and having its own API call to commit it, so:

```
cursor.execute( "CREATE TABLE t1 ( t1_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT )" )
cursor.commit()
cursor.execute( "CREATE TABLE t2 ( t2_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT )" )
cursor.commit()
```

In my opinion, this is a serious, glaring design error of Python's DB-API, making it a serious hassle to execute commands outside of transactions and to have proper control over transactions, eg. to use things like SQLite's `BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION`.  It's as if someone with no real database experience was allowed to design the API...

Comment: +1, or you can just set __autocommit__ to true in the first place which is disable by default; like this `cursor.connection.autocommit(True)`, .

Comment: @singularity: But if you do that, you're changing the behavior of the API at a low level--that can bite you if you're passing the connection to third-party code, for example.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard : no it's not , it will just enable __autocommit__ option for the cursor connection that we have created in our code :), enabling autocommit can be very helpful in some cases , when we want real time saving rather than doing each time `cursor.commit()` ...

Comment: @singularity: It is: it causes the API to no longer wrap blocks of commands in a transaction, which code now depends on it's the default behavior of DB-API.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: yes it is, with autocommit enable each database operation will be in its own transaction, in the other hand with autocommit disable the transaction will be extend over multiple operations, i'm not saying that autocommit don't have it own draw back for that matter, the standard pep 249 advise to disable "autocommit" by default , because explicit commit() are better , but sometimes the overhead of a opening an old transaction each time can slow things, a doc that can help: http://www.oreillynet.com/databases/blog/2007/02/mysql_transactions_and_autocom.html

Comment: @singularity: No, you're missing the point.  You don't run each operation in its own transaction; the point is to allow the user to start and commit transactions himself, as it should be, including the ability to give parameters to `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and the ability to run commands outside of any transaction (eg. Postgresql's `VACUUM` command can not be used inside a transaction).  The API should not be trying to magically abstract away transactions; that should be left to the user.  You can disable this behavior with autocommit, but again, that breaks code that doesn't expect it.

Comment: Your answer explains why the exception occurs. It seems that I will have to execute these scripts using spawned mysql process instead of mysqldb wrapper as I can't guarantee that the script (external to my tool) doesn't include transaction block(s). Thanks for your help.

Comment: There may be an option to disable automatic transactions with API extensions.  Psycopg for Postgresql has an "autocommit" setting; I don't know about MySQL.

Comment: acccording to the documentation at http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples there is no commit method on the cursor object - I get an AttributeError when I try to use this answer.

Comment: commit is available on the connection object http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#connection-objects - I will update the sample code to reflect this. Perhaps it used to be on the cursor objects?