# syncdb command not working properlly

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-models

I am trying to run the existing project.I had restored my database and installed all the required dependencies.While running syncdb,i got the below errors.

```
[root@localhost ]# python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 459, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 231, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 103, in get_validation_errors
    connection.validation.validate_field(e, opts, f)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 14, in validate_field
    db_version = self.connection.get_server_version()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 415, in get_server_version
    self.cursor().close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/utils/tracking/__init__.py", line 9, in wrapped
    return callback(original, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql.py", line 21, in cursor
    result = original(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 306, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 387, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 215, in __init__
    self.set_character_set(charset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 294, in set_character_set
    super(Connection, self).set_character_set(charset)
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")
```

Comment: Can i get any solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you compounding sql statements?

For example: cursor.execute('show databases; show tables;')?

If so, try splitting them up:

cursor.execute('')
cursor.close
reconnect
repeat

Comment: Where should i check this, whether in my application's models.py or in cursors.py

Comment: Can you please explain me where to made changes.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kalinakov mentioned this error is due to some improper use of cursors in your code. Please search for cursor.execute in your code and start debugging.

Also look at the below post which mentions why one gets these kind of errors and what is the solution -
[Ways to avoid MySQLdb's "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" (2014) exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707957/ways-to-avoid-mysqldbs-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now)

Answer (score 0):

Let's start a small debugging tour:

- 1) Is your database properly configured?
   Let's try it without the mySQL database and a SQlite. If you don't have any programming errors - SQLite will start out directly and sync your database. For this you need to go to your
   `settings.py` and reconfigure your database to something like here:

  ```
  DATABASES = {
  'default': {
  'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
  'NAME': 'database.db',                      

  'USER': '',
  'PASSWORD': '',
  'HOST': '',                     
  'PORT': '',
  ```

  }
  }
- 2) Now, run `syncdb` and see if it works. If it works now, you probably need to reconfigure your database: `name`, `password`, `host` and `port`. If SQlite does not work - please come back here and tell us there exact error messages.