# Getting "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Tags: python

Please forgive me, I am fairly new to python and I've been looking at the logic to this segment for quite a bit of time, however, no matter what I try, it appears that it always crashes at the print statement. Basically, I just want to find out if python is getting the correct values back from the SQL statement.  I have even tried doing a 
`a,b,c = row.split(',')` then `print a` but it errors out on the print a also.

```
with con:
    cur.execute(query, (next, end,next,end))
    print (cur._last_executed)  # this prints the correct query.
    while True:
        result = cur.fetchmany()
        if len(result) ==0:
            break
        for row in result:
            myvalues = row.split(',')
            for value in myvalues:
                print value # this line is what the traceback says caused it.
```

Error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./export.py", line 55, in <module>
    print value
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 249, in __exit__
       self.rollback()
    _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")
    Exception _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now") in <bound method SSCursor.__del__ of <MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor object at 0x7fc0e0632f10>> ignored
```

Comment: I guess `row` is not a string, so `row.split` looks wrong...

Comment: The traceback clearly indicates that the error occurs when you call `self.rollback()`, which doesn't even appear in the code you provided.  Moreover, how do you expect us to debug how your commands got out of sync if you don't show the commands that you're running?

Comment: Please show the complete traceback -- from the error information you've provided, it doesn't look like the `print value` line is what caused the exception.

Comment: The error actually happens when you exit the context manager - the one you enter by doing `with con:`. The connection starts to close, issues a `rollback`, which triggers the error. Not sure why this happens. Did you try calling `cur.close()` at the end of the `with` block?

Comment: The error is occurring when you exit the context manager (the `with` block), not at the `print` statement. My guess is that you've got SQL commands that are conflicting with the Python DB API's commands. I'm guessing in particular that you might have a `"COMMIT;"` in your query, which could cause this error (as seen in [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4707957/2069350)).

Comment: @letitbee I initially did, but I commented it out and the results are the same.

Comment: It will also help if you show us the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is happening when you exit the `with` block and `connection.__exit__` is called, not at the print statement.
When you look at this part of MySQLdb code, you see:

```
def __enter__(self): return self.cursor()

def __exit__(self, exc, value, tb):
    if exc:
        self.rollback()
    else:
        self.commit()
```

So this immediately tells us two things:

1. There is a previous exception that is shadowed by `rollback()` call that itself causes an exception
2. Your first line should be) `with conn as cur:`, because `cur` will be assigned the result of `connection.__enter__()`.

It is hard to say why exactly you get this error, because we don't know where your cursor comes from. You should change your first line as suggested above and it will probably work. If not, get rid of the context manager entirely, and you will be able to see the original exception.