# Python call procedure

Tags: python, procedure

I have 2 problems with my procedure.

First problem is the procedure doesn't work from python and I don't know why.
Here is my python code:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="***",    # your host, usually localhost
                     user="***",                     # your username
                     passwd="***",                      # your password
                     db="***")                     # name of the data base
#  you must create a Cursor object. It will let
#  you execute all the queries you need
cursor = db.cursor()
args=('SugarSHape',10024,241)
cursor.callproc('p_add_fb_data', args)
```

My procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`leverate`@`%` PROCEDURE `p_add_fb_data`(IN p_username VARCHAR(45),IN p_impressions INT(45),IN p_linkClicks INT(45))
BEGIN
    DECLARE id INT(5);
    SELECT id_user FROM t_user WHERE t_user.username=p_username;

    INSERT INTO t_fb_data(Impressions,LinkClicks) 
        Values(p_impressions, p_linkClicks);
END
```

I know that id is useless, but I need it later.
If I start the procedure from workbench it works. But if my Python script starts I don't get a new line in my table.

My second problem is if I start the procedure some more time I got this error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python27\Leverate.py",
> line 76, in <module>
>     cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM t_user")   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 174, in
> execute
>     self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in
> defaulterrorhandler
>     raise errorclass, errorvalue ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")
```

My code for this problem:

```
for z in range(0,5):
    args=(Clients[z][1],data["results"][z]["impressions"],data["results"][z]["clicks"]);
    cursor.callproc('p_add_fb_data', args)
```

I hope it's not too much and that someone can help me.

Comment: This can happen, for example, if you are using mysql_use_result() and try to execute a new query before you have called mysql_free_result(). It can also happen if you try to execute two queries that return data without calling mysql_use_result() or mysql_store_result() in between.http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commands-out-of-sync.html - Did you `use_result()` or `store_result()`?

Comment: no. i try with this code only and it doesnt work, too.

Comment: Which line is line 76?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, "commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583083/python-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ways to avoid MySQLdb's “Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now” (2014) exception]
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707957/ways-to-avoid-mysqldbs-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now)

Comment: yes i believe also that this is the problem. but if i write curor.commit() after all my queries i got the erroe : AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'commit'